# Intercept theorem and centroid of a triangle

Tags: geometry

> On the sides $CA$ and $CB$ of triangle $ABC$ with centroid $G$ are chosen two points - $M$ and $N$. I should show that $M,N$ and $G$ lie on the same line iff $\dfrac{CA}{CM}+\dfrac{CB}{CN}=3$.
>   [image]

Let me show you my thoughts about the problem.

Let points $M,G$ and $N$ lie on the same line and let $C_1$ be the midpoint of $AB$. My idea is to draw a line through $C_1$ that is parallel to $MN$. If the  constructed line intersects the rays $CA$ and $CB$ at $M_1$ and $N_1$, respectively, $\dfrac{CA}{CM_1}+\dfrac{CB}{CN_1}=2$ (a ratio that is often used in problems about the Intecept theorem). Let us apply the Intecept theorem for two angles:

1) $\angle N_1CM_1$ $(M_1N_1 \parallel MN)$, so $\dfrac{CM}{CM_1}=\dfrac{CN}{CN_1}$

2) $\angle N_1CC_1$ $(M_1N_1 \parallel MN)$, so $\dfrac{CN}{CN_1}=\dfrac{CG}{CC_1}=\dfrac{2}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{CM}{CM_1}=\dfrac{CN}{CN_1}=\dfrac{CG}{CC_1}=\dfrac{2}{3}$.

I think everything seems fine but I can't finish the problem from here.

P.P. I know that I should see if $\dfrac{CA}{CM}+\dfrac{CB}{CN}=3$ is enough for $M,N,G$ to lie on the same line. I just want to finish this case first. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Menelaus Theorem]

In this proof we use Menelaus' theorem instead of intercept theorem, which was suggested by the OP. Let $G$ be the centroid of the triangle $ABC$ and $A_1$ and $B_1$ the midpoints of $CB$ and $CA$ respectively. $MN$ is an arbitrary line passing through $G$. Our aim is to show, 
$$\frac{CA}{CM}+\frac{CB}{CN}=3.$$

Consider the triangle $CMN$ and the line $AA_1$. Applying Menelaus theorem yields,
$$\frac{CA_1}{NA_1}\frac{GN}{GM}\frac{MA}{CA}=1.$$
We substitute $CA_1=\frac{CB}{2}$, $NA_1=CN-\frac{CB}{2}$, and $MA=CA-CM$ in the above equation to get,
$$\frac{CB}{2CN-CB}\frac{GN}{GM}\frac{CA-CM}{CA}=1.\tag{1}$$

Consider the same triangle $CMN$ and the line $BB_1$. Again we apply Menelaus theorem and obtain,
$$\frac{CB_1}{MB_1}\frac{GM}{GN}\frac{NB}{CB}=1.$$
We substitute $CB_1=\frac{CA}{2}$, $MB_1=CM-\frac{CA}{2}$, and $NB=CB-CN$ in the above equation to get,
$$\frac{CA}{2CM-CA}\frac{GM}{GN}\frac{CB-CN}{CB}=1.\tag{2}$$

We multiply the equation (1) by the equation(2) to get,
$$\frac{CA-CM}{2CN-CB}\times \frac{CB-CN}{2CM-CA}=1.$$
The denominator and the numerator can be expanded and then cross-multiplied as shown below.
$$CB.CA+CN.CM-CB.CM-CA.CN=CB.CA+4CN.CM-2CB.CM-2CA.CN $$
This can be simplified to,
$$CB.CM+CA.CN=3CN.CM.$$
Once we divide the whole thing by $CN.CM$, we have,
$$\frac{CA}{CM}+\frac{CB}{CN}=3.$$